# IPTables port forward Remote mysql to localhost

Tags: iptables

i have a MySQL server`1.1.1.1` and I need port 3306 in `1.1.1.1:3306`
port forward to my secondary server `2.2.2.2:3306` I don't have access to MySQL server.

i have tried

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to 1.1.1.1:3306
```

how will i get this to work with iptables, its confusing.

Comment: Show use your complete rules: `iptables-save`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to forward MySQL connections to 2.2.2.2:3306 you will need these commands:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to 2.2.2.2:3306
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 2.2.2.2 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: i cant use MASQUERADE

Answer (score 0):

If you need temporary workaround you can use ssh port forwarding

```
ssh -R 3306:1.1.1.1:3306 127.0.0.1 -N
```

In this case you have to permit GatewayPorts in sshd_config

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

Also do not forget to open this port in iptables